# Inserting string variable into sql string in vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I am having a hard time inserting WONum into my sql string.
I have tried using ' and double '' around WONum. Someone also suggested # and [] around it, but nothing is working thus far.

I keep getting the following error: Incorrect syntax near '1577'

WONum value is actually WO-1577 during run time, but when DA.fill is executed I get that error. I starting to think that the dash is doing something in sql that I'm not aware of. Any help would help, because I have to do several more similar functions in my application.

```
Public Function GetTechTimes(ByVal WONum As String)

    Dim strSQL As String = "Select customer_name, workorder_work_to_be_performed, workorder_work_performed, workorder_notes, workorder_warranty_work, workorder_open_date, workorder_status,workorder_completion_date, wo_tech_name, wo_tech_time, wo_parts_description from Customers, workorders, WorkOrder_Technicians, WorkOrder_Parts Where(customer_id = workorder_customer And wo_tech_wo_id = workorder_id And wo_parts_wo_id = workorder_id And workorder_number = " & WONum & ""
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS, "TechTimes")
    Return DS
End Function
```

Comment: is this possible `select <fields>... from Customers, 
workorders, 
WorkOrder_Technicians, 
WorkOrder_Parts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `workorder_number` is a string then putting single quote ' around the WONum is all you need.

You won't need # or square brackets.

If it's not working with the single quote then ensure you've identified/isolated your problem correctly. Remove the `And workorder_number = " & WONum & ""` from the end of your sql and see if it works without that. If not, then your problem isn't in the WONum, it's earlier in the string.

Comment: Thanks man, single ' did work but that was not the real problem. The was a stray ( in the string.

Comment: @user1983938 in that case +1 from me to Tim, he spotted that

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Sql-Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)! That will avoid conversion or other issues and - more important - prevents [**SQL-Injection attacks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
Public Function GetTechTimes(ByVal WONum As String) As DataSet
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT customer_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_work_to_be_performed," & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_work_performed, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_notes, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_warranty_work, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_open_date, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_status, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "workorder_completion_date," & Environment.NewLine & _
    "wo_tech_name, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "wo_tech_time, " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "wo_parts_description" & Environment.NewLine & _
    "FROM(customers," & Environment.NewLine & _
    "       workorders," & Environment.NewLine & _
    "       workorder_technicians," & Environment.NewLine & _
    "       workorder_parts)" & Environment.NewLine & _
    "WHERE customer_id = workorder_customer " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "AND wo_tech_wo_id = workorder_id " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "AND wo_parts_wo_id = workorder_id " & Environment.NewLine & _
    "AND workorder_number = @workorder_number "

    Using con = New SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
        Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder_number", WONum)
            Dim DS As New DataSet
            da.Fill(DS)
            Return DS
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Note that i've also used `Using`-statements to ensure that all gets diposed even in case of an exception.

Bye the way, the reason for your exception: you had an opening brace here: `Where(customer_id` which was never closed.

Comment: sir, if you don't mind, i just want to ask, what kind of query `from Customers, workorders, WorkOrder_Technicians, WorkOrder_Parts`? thank you

Comment: I cannot understand your question. _"what kind of query from Customers, workorders, WorkOrder_Technicians, WorkOrder_Parts"_ ?

Comment: i meant `select <fields>.. from table, table, table` is that what we call a select `from multiple tables`? sorry for my dump question :)

Comment: @spajce: I don't know if someone calls that "select multiple tables". Normally i would say _join tables_. But your (old-style) way to join tables is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). I would have shown you the better `JOIN` sql, but i didn't know your schema (the column-names, PK,FK).

Comment: wow.. thank you for that very informative answer, this things i don't know until this question was created, thank you much again sir :)